# How to user query builder phalcon

Tags: php, laravel, phalcon, builder

I wanted to query the phalcon database like laravel's query builder, but I got this error and I'm sure I've called the correct model name:

```
error: Model 'work_staffs' could not be loaded
```

Model:

```
use Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault;

class WorkStaffModel
{

  public static function getAll()
  {
    $di = FactoryDefault::getDefault()->get('modelsManager')
    ->createBuilder();

    $result = $di
    ->from('work_staffs')
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();

    return $result;
  }
}
```

/PUBLIC/INDEX:

```
use Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Application;
use Phalcon\Loader;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Manager as ModelsManager;

$di     = new FactoryDefault;
$app    = new Application;
$loader = new Loader;

$loader->registerDirs(
[
    dirname(__DIR__) . '/app/controllers',
    dirname(__DIR__) . '/app/models',
    dirname(__DIR__) . '/service'
]
);

$loader->register();

include dirname(__DIR__) . '/lib/core.php';
include dirname(__DIR__) . '/lib/di.php'; 
// HERE DI INCULE DI FILE BUT IN DI FILE JUST INCLUDED:set conf,router,seesion,view

try
{

  date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh');
  $app->setDi($di);

  $res = $app->handle();
  $res->send();
}

catch(Exception $e)
{
  if($e->getMessage() != 'Response was already sent') {

    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

I did not set DI modelsManager, but in model it still works, but the Model `work_staffs` error could not be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `work_staffs` is a table, not model.  The QueryBuilder class uses Models to select from.

In `app/models/WorkStaffs.php` you should have something that at a minimum is like the following:

```
<?php
    class WorkStaffs extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model {
    }
```

Which you could then use anywhere.  You're using the FactoryDefault dependency injector, so you have the model service in place already.  At that point, in your controller it's really easy to work with, using `WorkStaffs::find()` to get all of the results in the table.

Comment: thank jellisii, add extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model not working for me

Comment: @newsshare24h Make sure that your class name matching database name and filename is in camel case.

Answer (score 0):

1/You should have the Model file(php) : WorksStaffs.php in the folder of model

```
<?php
class WorkStaffs extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model {
}
```

2/In the clause 'From' of QueryBuilder, you should inject the namespace of your 'Workstaffs' Model

```
$di = FactoryDefault::getDefault()->get('modelsManager')
->createBuilder();

$result = $di
->from('WorkStaffs');
```

Hope it can help you